# Realm querying with two conditions at the same time

Tags: android, realm

How would I query a structure like this:

```
public class Animal extends RealmObject { 
    RealmList<Bird> birds;
}


public class Bird extends RealmObject { 
    int type;
    RealmList<RealmInteger> species;
}
```

RealmInteger is an object with an `int value`

I want to find all `Animal` objects that have `Bird` which has a species of `value` 3 AND that `Bird` is of `type` 2

I tried this but it keeps ignoring the `type`:

```
realm.where(Animal.class)
    .equalTo("birds.type", 2)
    .equalTo("birds.species.value", 3)
    .findAll();
```

My guess is it finds a match with value but doesn't check the type field at the same time. I need a way of doing `.equalTo("birds.species.value", 3)` to check only Birds of `type` 2?

**Update**:
Tried the @EpicPandaForce answer below, it is also returning this Animal with the data:

```
"birds": [
     {
        "species": [3, 15, 26],
        "type": 1
     },
     {
        "species": [],
        "type": 2,
     }
]
```

Because this `Animal` does not have a species `value` of 3 (it's empty) of `type` 2, it should NOT return it. Yet it does.

Comment: `birds` is a`RealmList` so u can't  directly access `type` field. get the Bird object and then access its type.

Comment: *birds is aRealmList so u can't directly access type field* yes you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are running into a peculiarity of how link queries work, and currently, there is no easy way to do what you want.

The underlying reason is that you are querying from the point of view of `Animal` and that you have two levels of `RealmList`. What you are after is a sort of sub-query that isn't yet supported by Realm. The details of how link queries work are described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries. I would highly recommend working through the example in those docs.

That said, it is still possible to achieve what you want, but you need a combination of our newly added `@LinkingObjects` annotation + some manually work to do it. Here is how:

```
// Animal class must have a stable hashcode. I did it by adding a primary key
// here, but it can be done in multiple ways.
public class Animal extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    public RealmList<Bird> birds;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Make sure you have a stable equals/hashcode
        // See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmobjects-hashcode
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Animal animal = (Animal) o;
        return id.equals(animal.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}

// Add a @LinkingObjects field to Bird
// See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#inverse-relationships
public class Bird extends RealmObject {
    public int type;
    public RealmList<RealmInteger> species;
    @LinkingObjects("birds")
    public final RealmResults<Animal> animalGroup = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bird{" +
                "type=" + type +
                '}';
    }
}

// Query the birds instead of Animal
RealmResults<Bird> birds = realm.where(Bird.class)
        .equalTo("type", 2)
        .equalTo("species.value", 3)
        .findAll();

// You must collect all Animals manually
// See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2232
Set<Animal> animals = new HashSet<>();
for (Bird bird : birds) {
    animals.addAll(bird.animalGroup);
}
```

Comment: Great. Hopefully in the future Realm will support this directly so I won't need to add them manually via a for loop.

Comment: Also, this seems a bit less readable and extra work to me then just querying for all birds of a specific type via Realm then checking their species list for a specific value manually. Not sure at the performance hit this way though.

Answer (score 2):

```
realm.where(Animal.class)
  .equalTo("birds.type", 2)
  .findAll()
  .where()
  .equalTo("birds.species.value", 3)
  .findAll();
```

This trick is only needed for multiple link queries.

Comment: i need a `where()` after the first `findAll()`. but it still doesn't work

Comment: how to get `.equalTo("birds.species.value", 3)` to check only Birds of `type` 2?

Comment: @ono This answer should work. You can find more details about the similar problem here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries If it still doesn't work, please share more details.

Comment: @beeender added the data. let me know if it helps.